# Error while inserting data with stored procedure in table with shared identity primary key

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, identity

I've got a few tables linked together where data should be inserted to using a stored procedure. The tables are:

```
create table contactpersoon
(
    contactpersoonnr    integer identity(1,1),
    klantnr             integer,
    naam                varchar(50) not null,
    telefoonnr          varchar(10) not null,
    emailadres          varchar(50) not null,

    constraint pk_contactpersoon 
        primary key(contactpersoonnr, klantnr),
    constraint fk_contactpersoon_klantnr 
        foreign key(klantnr) references klant(klantnr)
)

create table klant 
(
    klantnr        integer identity(1,1) primary key,
    bedrijfsnaam   varchar(50) not null
)

create table Logins
(
    GebruikersNaam  varchar(30),
    Wachtwoord      varchar(30),
    Klantnr         int,
    MdwNr           int,

    constraint pk_logID primary key(GebruikersNaam),
    constraint fk_klantnr foreign key(klantnr) references klant(klantnr),
    constraint fk_mdwnr foreign key(mdwnr) references medewerker(mdwnr)
)
```

Stored procedure for adding data to these tables:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'spKlantAanmaken') 
   DROP PROCEDURE spKlantAanmaken
GO 

Create Procedure spKlantAanmaken
(
    @bedrijfsnaam as varchar(255),
    @contactnaam as varchar(255),
    @telnr as integer,
    @email as varchar(255),
    @gebruikersnaam as varchar(255),
    @wachtwoord as varchar(255)
)
AS
Begin transaction 
Declare @klantnr integer
Declare @contactpersoonnr integer

Insert into Klant Values (@klantnr, @bedrijfsnaam);
Insert into contactpersoon values(@contactpersoonnr, @klantnr, @contactnaam, @telnr, @email);
Insert into Logins values (@gebruikersnaam, @wachtwoord ,@klantnr, NULL);
Select * from contactpersoon
    IF @@ERROR <> 0 
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK 
        RAISERROR ('Error tijdens uitvoeren van stap 2.', 16, 1) 
        RETURN 
    END 
    COMMIT 
GO
```

I don't know if it is necessary to use these identity values in the inserts. 
If I try this stored procedure I get the following error:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spKlantAanmaken, Line 923
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Klant' can only be
>   specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

If I remove the identity values from the insert I get this error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spKlantAanmaken, Line 923
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use the identity columns in the insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Identity`, the columns on which the `identity` is applied need not be in your `INSERT` statement `VALUES`. So edit your code like below

**EDIT**

It also seems you are missing out the columns you are trying to insert into

```
Insert into Klant (bedrijfsnaam) Values (@bedrijfsnaam)
Insert into contactpersoon (klantnr, contactnaam, telnr, email) Values (@klantnr, @contactnaam, @telnr, @email)
```

It seems all the answers saying the same thing so hope your issued is solved

Comment: You will need to provide a column list. This code will throw errors

Comment: Fixed it!! Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `identity` columns, you **must** specify the list of columns to insert into, in your `INSERT` statement, and *not supply* a value for the identity column - like this:

Instead of

```
Insert into Klant Values (@klantnr, @bedrijfsnaam);
```

use

```
Insert into Klant(bedrijfsnaam) Values (@bedrijfsnaam);
```

and do this for **all** your `INSERT` operations.

This is a generally accepted "Best Practice" for *any* time you insert something into a table - it is recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of columns in your table that you're inserting into (to avoid annoying errors and surprises).

Answer (score 0):

Edit these two lines in your SP

```
Insert into Klant (bedrijfsnaam) 
Values (@bedrijfsnaam);
Insert into contactpersoon(klantnr,naam,telefoonnr,emailadres)
values(@klantnr, @contactnaam, @telnr, @email);
```

Provide a column list, excluding the `identity` columns in the `insert` statements

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the `identity` columns `klantnr`, `contactpersoonnr` in the INSERT query and explicitly define your column names:

So the below code will work in your case:

```
Insert into Klant(bedrijfsnaam) Values (@bedrijfsnaam);

Insert into contactpersoon(klantnr, naam, telefoonnr, emailadres) values(@klantnr, @contactnaam, @telnr, @email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the column names AND the contents in the INSERT statement like:

```
INSERT INTO klant (bedrijfsnaam) VALUES ('XYZ');
```

If you don't specify the column name list, the SQL interpreter implies, you want the identity column, too. In this case you would want to set data for 2 columns, but only provide one content element, which explains the latter error message.